# Why do I get an error when trying to add a web reference in a Script Task (SSIS)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, ssis, web-reference, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to add a web reference in a SSIS-package on a clients server in order to communicate with a web service.

In my script task I'm able to add the web reference, reference it in the code, build successfully and save it.

**BUT** when I exit the script task editor I get a script error saying ***"Script contained in the package have compilation errors. Do you want to save changes?"***

If I press Yes here my script task gets an red cross on it and it says ***"The binary code for the script is not found.".***

Even if I create a new poject, add a script task, add the web reference (no other code in the Script Task) with the same result.

However, it works great adding the same reference as a service reference instead, no errors. The problem is that the owner of this webservice said explicitly that I had to use a web reference since it's methods are VS2005 Web Service methods.

I tried the same thing on my local computer and it worked with web references! The only difference I could think of is that I use Microsft Visual Studio 2012 (Data Tools) on my local machine and the server uses Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (Data Tools).

I also tried to create the SSIS-package on my computer, move it to the server, open it (no errors if i didn't changed anything in the Script Task) and then run the package.
Got the following error message ***"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"***.

[image: Invocation error ssis]

In this case if I opened the Script Task and did any change (even add a comment) I got the same error (The binary code for the script is not found.) after exiting the Script Task.

**What I've tried:**

- Run project in both 32Bit Runtime and 64Bit Runtime.
- Set DelayValidation to True
- Change URL Behavior for the Web Reference to Static.
- Tried debugging, also "extended" debugging according to http://blog.fredrikhaglund.se/blog/2009/12/22/debugging-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation/.
- Checked the rights off the user running VS (In Component Services,
  Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 11.0), the user has full rights.
- Run Visual Studio as administrator.
- Add a web reference to a completely different web service, same error.

**Other information:**

- Server: Windows Server 2012
- Internet access on server
- .NET Framework 2.0,3.0,3.5 and 4.5 is installed on the server.
- Client Tools SDK and Client Tools Backwards Compatiblity is installed
  on the server.

I've search all over the web for people with a solution to this problem but haven't found any.
So I'm turning to SO, how can I solve this problem?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the TargetInvocation error ? One thing that you also can try is to save reference.cs when the webreference is added and add it as a class to your scripting component. And see if in that case the class is preserved.

Comment: I have updated the post with a picture of the error message. I was looking for the reference.cs file but couldn't find it anywhere in the project, even checked the solution folder. Where can I find it? Thanks.

Comment: In the project explorer of the scripting component, where you also see ScriptMain.cs there is an icon to show all files. Using that you can drilldown to the file reference.cs

Comment: Found it, and I actually got it to work! I added the web reference, copied the reference.cs, removed the web reference and then added reference.cs as a class in my Script Task. Had to uncomment one line in reference.cs and then I could use the reference as before. Ako, make sure to add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: It's ok, I am glad that it works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To overcome the disappearing webreference you can try to add the client proxycode manually to your solution:

1. Open Script component 'Select all files' icon in the solution explorer
2. Drill down to webreference, and locate reference.cs file
3. Copy the content of this file to a new class file.
4. Delete the webreference
5. Recompile your code, save and exit
6. Open your project to see whether the reference is saved.

Comment: Are there any downsides using this solution? It feels a little bit like a "quick-and-dirty" fix.

Comment: The downside is that you give up the flexibility that you can not right click and update the webreference when it might change.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest way is to search for the VSTA folder which should pop up under the C:\Users\Your User Directory\AppData\Local\Temp.

Right click on the VSTA folder and go to Properties.
Give the account holder full access.
Save and close Visual Studio
Reopen and it should be fine.